# é possível dois submit um botão?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

É Possivel, dentro de um click a chamada de dois submit?

Eis o meu problema, preciso que dentro de um button, seja chamada dois ActionResult em sequencia.

Segue o que já fiz até agora:

```
    $('#enviarPreProposta').click(function () {
    var telefoneValido = ValidarTelefones();
    var idUltimoTelefone = $('#tblTelefones tbody tr:last td:first input').val();
    if (idUltimoTelefone == undefined) {
        MessageBoxKo('É obrigatório a inclusão de pelo menos um telefone.', 'Atenção', null, null, null, null);
    return false;
    }

    var retorno = ValidarCamposNecessarios();
    if (retorno == true && telefoneValido) {
        DesabilitarCamposResposanvelFinanceiro();
        $('#frmVendaEletronica').attr('action', '../VendaAdministrativa/ValidarCampos')
        $('#frmVendaEletronica').submit();
        $('#frmVendaEletronica').attr('action', '../VendaAdministrativa/EnviarPrePropostaAceitacao')
        $('#frmVendaEletronica').submit();
    }
   });
```

Comment: A cada requisição a página é regarregada, portanto não é possivel e nem muito lógico fazer dois "submits", pois no primeiro submit a página já carrega. Mas existe uma solução, o Ajax, no entanto você terá que modificar a interface do back-end para poder obter a resposta, usando um formato mais amigavel para o ajax como o Json por exemplo. Todavia ao invés de ajax **talvez seja melhor** você criar uma rota única aonde ocorre todos eventos do back-end ao invés de ter duas rotas.

Comment: Você pode colocar um `return RedirectToAction()` em uma action ou trabalhar com ViewModels para isso. Poste o que precisa fazer que será mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: @Randrade, então meu querido, o problema é : tenho uma actionResult que retorna pra a tela um Dialog, e só posso seguir com o fluxo do sistema, caso o usuário preencha ou feche esse dialog, na sequencia, a aplicação chama outro actionResult.

Comment: Se você adicionar como está retornando esse diálogo e essas informações do comentário na pergunta, ficará mais fácil te ajudar. Explique o que realmente precisa fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possivel mas pode utilizar `$.post()`, por exemplo:

```
var dado1 = '123';
var dado2 = '456';
$.post('../VendaAdministrativa/ValidarCampos',{'dado1':dado1,'dado2':dado2},callback(){
  var dado1 = '789'; 
  var dado2 = '91011'; 
  $.post('../VendaAdministrativa/EnviarPrePropostaAceitacao',{'dado1':dado1,'dado2':dado2},callback(){
      //FIM
  }
})
```

Comment: Quando for formatar código, use o markdown, selecionando o código e clicando no botão `{}`

Comment: vlw, muito obrigado